# Can I use private methods?

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

I'm using awesomium WebControl.

I wanted to use method: `LoadURL(String)`. But it's a private method.  Is there a possible way to use private methods at all?

My code:

XAML:

```
<my:WindowsFormsHost Name="windowsFormsHost" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

Code behind [C#]

```
Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl Browser2 = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
        private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        windowsFormsHost.Child = Browser2;

        windowsFormsHost.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

And i wanted to use:

```
Browser2.LoadURL(String);
```

The method is here:
http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_3/sharp_api/?tc=163d5346-d13d-e0cf-49ba-72b2b04d7620

Comment: did you try reflection?

Comment: @Dilshod - While that may work, it's generally a bad idea. Private methods are usually private for a reason, and calling them directly is likely to break something.

Comment: LoadUrl is a public method...http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_3/sharp_api/?tc=163d5346-d13d-e0cf-49ba-72b2b04d7620  What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bobson yes you are right, but some times you have to.

Comment: No it's not possible.
Main if you are using OOP you need to follow the rules of OOPS
an in that you can not use Private by an object Best practice and proper class design in object oriented language(C#) http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/232598/Best-practice-and-proper-class-design-in-object-or

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is on that link that you believe is relevant.  Regardless, following OOP practices really doesn't have much to do with the actual problem the OP is faced with.  The method in question is public, not private as he stated.  So there is something else going on.

Comment: The method in question is not an Method. it's an class and this class also  an user defined class not an cor part of the .NET .

so you also can build your on class and this class inheriting the user control class 

and also use this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx#Members

for build your knowledge

Comment: Huh?  `WebControl` is part of the awesomium kit.  `LoadUrl()` is a method of that control.  He's not descending from anything, just simply asking how to call the `LoadUrl()` method and making a faulty statement that it's private.  Either way, even if he was to descend from an existing class you still couldn't call private methods on the parent class.  Nothing about OOP practices applies here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't call private methods.

Private members are accessible only within the body of the class or the struct in which they are declared